# How to check if variable is NOT something

Tags: c, variables, char, comparison-operators

Basically I want to check if `char a` is not `'y'` or `'n'`. Been trying to figure it out for an hour now and could not find anything.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int yesno(char a){
    do{
        printf(":");
        scanf("%s",&a);
        if((a!='y')||(a!='n')){
            printf("Incorrect awnser, try again\n");
        }
    }while((a!='y')||(a!='n'));
}
int main(){
    printf("************************************\n");
    printf("*Welcome to 'noname' 0.01          *\n");
    printf("*Do you want to start y/n?         *\n");
    printf("************************************\n");
    yesno(1);
return 0;
}
```

Could someone tell me how to do that? How to make it check if something is NOT something.
This code is what my understanding of C allows me to create, but it's not working correctly, it just loops:
**Incorrect answer, try again**

Comment: If a equals y then it does NOT equal n (and vice versa). One of your conditions will always be true and likewise the whole test due to the || (or). Use && (and) instead

Comment: that and change format specifier `scanf("%s",&a);` => `scanf(" %c",&a);`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Did that, but my I ask what is the reason for what?

Comment: `%s` is used when the parameter is char * not char

Comment: Note that your `yesno` code doesn't return a value and can't change the variable in `main` because the parameter is not passed as a pointer.  Granted, you don't try to use the value that isn't returned, but you will soon need to start doing so.  Indeed, it is not clear why you're passing anything to the function `yesno()`.

Comment: You need to look for a good formal logic text, because this is about as simple as it gets.

Comment: regarding your question, try to remember your 'logic' class.  regarding: `if((a!='y')||(a!='n')){`  if 'a' is 'y', then 'a' != 'n' so the body of the `if()` code block will be entered.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&a);` will not work, as `a` is a single character and `%s` will try to read a whole string of unlimited length.  suggest: `a = getchar();`  or `scanf( " %c", &a );`  Note the leading space in the format string

Comment: use && like pinkfloydx33 said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **continue** and **break** statements inside the if condition.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int yesno(char a){

    do{

        printf(":");
        scanf("%s",&a);
        if((a=='y')||(a=='n')){
            break;
        }
        else{
            printf("Incorrect answer, try again\n");
            continue;           
        }

    }while((a!='y')||(a!='n'));
}

int main(){

    printf("************************************\n");
    printf("*Welcome to 'noname' 0.01          *\n");
    printf("*Do you want to start y/n?         *\n");
    printf("************************************\n");
    yesno(1);

return 0;
}
```

I just changed the if condition and added the else part.

Answer (score 1):

```
"if((a!='y')||(a!='n')){
    printf("Incorrect awnser, try again\n");
}"
```

You could use a switch-case statement, with the default being the printf() statement.

```
switch(a) {
    case 'y':
    // do nothing
    break;
    case 'n':
    // do nothing
    break;
    default:
    printf("Incorrect answer, try again\n");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, you should use the `&&` operator instead of `||` to check if `a` is neither `'y'` nor `'n'` like

```
    if((a!='y') && (a!='n')){
        printf("Incorrect awnser, try again\n");
    }
}while((a!='y') && (a!='n'));
```

The condition `((a!='y') || (a!='n'))` will always be true as `a` cannot be `'y'` and `'n'` at the same time.

And in `yesno()`, `a` is a `char` and not a `char` array capable of holding strings.

So

```
scanf("%s",&a);
```

should be

```
scanf("%c",&a);
```

as the format specifier for a `char` is `%c` whereas `%s` is for strings.

Even if `a` were a `char` array to store a string, the `scanf()` should've been

```
scanf("%s",a);
```

as array name in C decay into pointer to its base element.

---

And you could do away with that argument of `yesno()` as the initial value of `a` is irrelevant since a new value of `a` is read in at the beginning of `yesno()` and any changes made to `a` will not have any repercussion back in `main()` as  the parameter is passed by value and `yesno()` doesn't return a value.

So, instead of making `a` a parameter, you could make it a local variable of `yesno()` like

```
void yesno(){//or yesno(void)
    char a;
    do
    {
        printf(":");
        scanf("%c",a);
        if((a!='y') && (a!='n')){
            printf("Incorrect awnser, try again\n");
        }
    }while((a!='y') && (a!='n'));
}
```

And call it like

```
yesno();
```

in `main()`.